# IE addon writen by C# can't run on some windows system

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser-addons, ieaddon

I write an IE addon by C# and .net 4.0. But it not run on most computers of clients.

I setup this addon by following steps.

1. install .net 4.0
2. add the addon dll to GAC by run

   .\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /f /i Addon.dll
3. Register dll to IE by run

   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" Addon.dll

After those steps, I could find my addon in ie. It is avaliable and enabled, but could not work. It works well on my computer. but not on other pc.

Comment: I thing windows have installed client profile in their computer and you have ported to .net 4 full framework.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check what CPU you are targeting with your build. If you are specifically targeting 64-bit and then running on 32-bit, this could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why this could happen.  For instance, there may be some other .net component already loaded in memory that requires a different version of the framework.  Whichever version of the framework that loads first wins, and only one can be loaded at any given time.

This is one reason that you should not write Explorer or IE extensions in managed code, since you cannot control what version of the framework may already be loaded in the process.

It might also be a 32 bit assembly, trying to load into a 64 bit process, or vice versa.

It could also be that your component is not fully implementing the correct interfaces.

Since there is no other information, it's hard for us to diagnose the problem.